# Qt Visual Studio Plugin - "Couldn't connect to QtAppWrapper server"

Tags: visual-studio-2008, qt, add-in

I have been working with Qt and Visual Studios 2008 for a while now.  However, the other day after a reboot, the add-in to visual studios stopped working.

**What's working:**

- templates and wizards.
      I can add new items either ui, qrc, or even projects (although I
  haven't tried it)
- Building existing projects - any files already setup to moc or uid or whatever, that works fine.

**What's not working:**

- The Qt menu is not there. I can't access the Qt project properties (usually found when right-clicking on a project)
- Using the Qt editors such as Designer. When I double-click a UI file, I get the following error:

  **"*Couldn't connect to QtAppWrapper server Expected server address
  127.0.0.1:12005***
- Any automatic 'stuff' that VS used to do.  Ex.  When you add the Q_OBJECT macro, it would add your generated files to the project.

**What I have tried/investigated:**

I have tried rebooting, restarting VS, un-installing and re-installing the Qt Addin, upgrading to a new version of the Qt Addin.  All to no avail.

There doesn't appear to be any trouble-shooting help on the Qt web-site.  I saw someone asked a similar question on the Qt forums, but there was no answer.

I was working with 1.1.7, I upgraded to 1.1.8 to see if that would help.

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be with Visual Studios.  It was unable to read the .addin file.

So if you look in the add-in manager you will notice that any add-ins using .addin files are not listed.

The actual problem is with the MSXML components installation.  I had v4.0, but there could be issues with other versions as well.

For a fuller explanation see [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/6778e3a2-2783-4826-a5f2-7089e1c8fb90).

So following their suggestion I uninstalled MSXML, (v4.0), and installed the 6.0 SP1 version that they linked to.  At that point, all the .addin defined addins appeared in the add-in manager.  At this point, you may have to re-enable it.

In my case, I had to un-install the Qt add-in, and re-install it before it worked completely.

I had the error "QtAppWrapper can't be found in the installation directory"

But upon re-installation of the addin, everything starting working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this happen to me.  Somehow the VS add-in was turned off.  Just go to...

`Tools > Add-in Manager`

...and re-enable the plug-in and you should be good to go.

If it isn't showing up, you can download the latest version (currently 1.1.9 as of this writing) from here: [Visual Studio QT Add-in](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/visual-studio-add-in).

However, if you are using VS 2010 and QT 4.7.2 or 4.7.3 (same instructions, just change the linked URL to the download to end in 4.7.2 or 4.7.3 accordingly) then follow these instructions...

[Using Qt 4.7.3 in Visual Studio 2010](http://thomasstockx.blogspot.com/2011/03/qt-472-in-visual-studio-2010.html)

That's what I had to do to get it all working.

However, a caveat: Since I too had already installed everything via Nokia's installers, I ran into issues following the steps on Thomas' blog.  To fix, I first uninstalled everything QT-related, then manually went through the registry and deleted out all related keys that pointed to my old QT path.  Then I followed his instructions, and I was good to go!  Took FOR-EV-ER (over a half hour to configure and compile alone) but it worked.

On a side-note, I posted comments on his blog two days ago and he answered in a couple of hours, so it's still a very active blog.

HTH!

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it and let you know.

Comment: Hmmm... The Add-in manager doesn't show anything at all.  That could be part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am using VS2010 with QT4.7 add-in. It has been working well all the time until I installed the quicktime plug-in and the same problem appeared. So I just removed the quicktime and the problem is solved! Maybe you can give a try if you also got a quicktime thing.